# Enterprise Certificate Apple

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate, ios-provisioning

I'm using enterprise certificate of apple and I create an application using that certificate.Peoples are using the app.problem is,enterprise certificate is going to expire in next month and I want to renew it.can anyone tell me what should I do? and are there any issues on app if I do not renew it? and after renew the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to renew the developer account. Go to the [Apple Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/).

> Distribution provisioning profiles expire 12 months after they’re issued. Two months before expiration, the iOS device begins displaying notifications about the impending expiration. After the expiration date, the app won’t launch.
>
> Before to a provisioning profile expires, use the iOS Development Portal to create a new profile for the app. Create a new app archive (.ipa) with the new provisioning profile, for users who are installing the app for the first time.

You can also [Contact Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, p12, the description has expired in one year, it will be regenerated, and then sign your own application, otherwise it will show verification, the application can not be opened. You regenerate it just fine